# writing on a txt file in C using fwrite function

Tags: c, file, fwrite

I'm trying to create a txt file from a vector, but my txt file is filled with trash values, below the code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    float x,v[15],aux=0;
    FILE *arq;

    arq = fopen("base.txt", "wt");
    if (arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return;
    }
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    for (j =0; j < 50; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            x = (rand() % 100);
            x = x/100;
            printf("%.2f \t", x);
            v[i] = x;
        }
        for (k=0; k<15; k++){
            aux += v[k];
        }
        if (aux > 0 && aux < 3)  {
            v[15] = 0.25;
        } else if (aux > 3 && aux < 7) {
            v[15] = 0.5;
        } else if (aux > 7 && aux < 12) {
            v[15] = 0.7;
        } else {
            v[15] = 1;
        }
        fprintf(v, sizeof(v), 50, arq);

    }
}
```

The correct output for my file should be 50 lines (j variable), on each line should be stored the values from vector v[] spaced like:

```
1 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.25
```

Is this problem occurring because of the fwrite function?

Comment: Use "wt" when you open the file, fprintf() to write text to it.

Comment: Using fprintf() and "wt" my code only runs one iteration of the first for loop. The txt file is blank now.

Comment: If you want the output to be human readable and not binary, use `fprintf()` to print out each element of the array one at a time.

Comment: @Shawn now its blank file, not even an ET can read now.

Comment: You have a `printf()` in your code so I assumed you know how to use it and related functions, but maybe not? Edit your post to show new code.

Comment: Oh, you also write past the end of your array, so all sorts of bad stuff can happen.

Comment: @Shawn the only thing I've changed was the "wb" for "wt" and the "fwrite" for "fprintf". I've edited the original post to show.

Comment: When you edit your post, include an edit to the title if needed. Your title mentions `fwrite`, but there's not a single use of `fwrite` in your question. Also, `float v[15]` would commonly be referred to as an array, as that's what it is; it's not a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fprintf()` call is nonsensical:

```
fprintf(v, sizeof(v), 50, arq);
```

The arguments to `fprintf()` are:

```
FILE *stream, const char *format, ...
```

You are passing an array of float as the FILE, and a size as the format string.

If your code compiles at all, it means your compiler either has all its important warnings disabled, or you are ignoring those warnings, or your compiler is a toy compiler which cannot diagnose obviously broken code.

Try compiling your code with something like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror`.  It will not compile at all, and the compiler will tell you (some of) what's wrong.

Comment: additionally there is never a newline "\n" printed so there will not be the 50 lines expected

Comment: @Bwebb: Of course there is no newline printed--there is no valid call to print anything at all, nor any format string.  Clearly OP simply replaced the word `fwrite` with `fprintf` and shovelled the code onto us without trying to fix it.